# Any way to manually trigger a Test Discovery pass in VS2019 from a VSPackage?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing, vspackage, visual-studio-sdk

We're currently building an internal apparatus to run unit tests on a large C++ codebase, using [Catch2](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2) for the framework and our in-house VS test adapter (using `[ITestDiscoverer]` and `ITestExecutor`) to attune them to our code practices. However, we've encountered issues with unit tests not always being discovered after a build.

There's a couple of things we're doing out of the norm that may be contributing. While we're using VS2019 for coding, we use [FASTBuild](https://www.fastbuild.org/docs/home.html) and [Sharpmake](https://github.com/ubisoft/Sharpmake) to build our solutions (which can contain countless projects). When we realised that VS would try to build the tests again using MSBuild before running them (even after a full rebuild), we disabled that behaviour in the VS options. Everything else seems to be running as expected, except that sometimes tests aren't picked up.

After doing some digging (namely outputting a verification message to VS's *Tests* Output the moment our TestDiscoverer is entered), it seems like a test discovery pass isn't always being invoked when we would expect it, sometimes even with a full solution rebuild. Beyond the usual expectation that building a project with new changes (or rebuilding outright) would cause a pass to start, the methodology VS uses to determine when to invoke all installed test adapters seems to be fairly blackbox in terms of what exact parameters/conditions trigger it.

An alternative seems to be to allow the user to manually execute a TD pass via some means that could be wrapped in a VSPackage. However, initial looks through the VSSDK API for anything that'd do the job has come up short.

**Using the VSSDK, are there any means to invoke a Test Discovery pass independently from VS's normal means of detecting whether a pass is required?**

Comment: I checked some related VSSDK, but I’m afraid, it seems there isn’t any interface(SDK) that may meet your requirement. I may suggest you also ask this issue here: [GitHub vstest-issues](https://github.com/microsoft/vstest/issues).

Answer (score 0):

You would want to use the ITestContainerDiscoverer.TestContainersUpdated event. The platform should then call into your Container Discoverer to get the latest set of containers (ITestContainerDiscoverer.TestContainers). As long as the containers returned from the discoverer are different(based on ITestContainer.CompareTo()) the platform should trigger a discovery for the changed containers. This blog has been quite helpful in the past: https://matthewmanela.com/blog/anatomy-of-the-chutzpah-test-adapter-for-vs-2012-rc/